# View needs Schema Reference

Tags: sql-server, schema

I have a Dev database that was cloned from a prod DB and was working just fine.  Suddenly, all view references in my SQL fail in my app because they need the schema reference to find the view.  I have checked both the view and the login (on the server and DB levels) and they all point to rw as the default schema.  Does anybody have any idea of what else might be causing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the SQL error text?  The problem isn't clear based on what you're saying.

Comment: I just get an "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'myView' ".  If I include the schema in my sql it will work fine.

Comment: SELECT default_schema_name 
FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE name = ''--put the name of the account the app runs under

Can you try that query?  Does it return the same schema as the view?

Comment: yes, it returns the same schema the apps runs under and that the view is stored under.

Comment: Is it possible that the account is an "sa" in the dev server?  That will cause the login to behave differently than in an environment that has less elevated rights.  Specifically, it may come in through the dbo schema as the default schema, which would cause the above error.

Comment: actually yes!  another developer had just requested that for a different problem.  I will have the rights remoked and see what happens.

Comment: Had the SA clear the permissions this morning, and everything went back to normal, thanks for the help!  Please make sure to give an official answer so I can give you the credit!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Answer posted.  I just don't like question/answer format for troubleshooting types of things, because you might have to try 5 things before you get it right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the comments...  Is it possible that the account is an "sa" in the dev server?  That will cause the login to behave differently than in an environment that has less elevated rights. Specifically, it may come in through the dbo schema as the default schema, which would cause the above error.